# Are recent claims from India of a car fueled by water and calcium carbide legitimate?

Tags: road-vehicles, chemistry

Recently, I came across a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2c9zxcT3tbU&nohtml5=False) and a [news report](http://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/a-mechanic-in-madhya-pradesh-just-invented-a-car-that-runs-on-fuel-as-cheap-as-rs-10-per-litre-246092.html) where it has been reported that a man from India has invented a car which uses water as a key fuel component. The car runs on acetylene gas produced by the reaction of water and calcium carbide in the car's fuel tank. The source of the video is [this post](https://www.facebook.com/238044912896496/videos/1159119444122367/) off Facebook from History TV18.

The claims are too good to be true and I doubt them. However, I do not know much about cars, automobile/mechanical engineering, and chemistry to check the veracity of the claims. How legitimate are the claims? Do they hold any merit?

Comment: This is like saying that they've developed a car that runs on air (oh, and some gasoline).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The car does not run on water. The article you link says quite clearly that "The car runs on acetylene gas".

Acetylene is an explosive gas that is used for welding, and before the invention of electric lamps it was  used for lighting. It is produced from the reaction of calcium carbide and water, as follows:

CaC<sub>2</sub> + 2H<sub>2</sub>O → Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> + C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>2</sub>

The problem is that, while water is cheap, CaC<sub>2</sub> is not. It is normally made from methane - which would be a better and cheaper fuel. Converting it to Calcium Carbide is done by partial combustion, so some of the energy available in methane is lost.

For more information on acetylene, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylene).

Comment: +1. Acetylene is what spelunkers' lamps used to use for fuel (and, for all I know, still may), so it's a very old technology and a very simple one.

Comment: Actually I think actylene lamps came long after torches :-)

Comment: @jamesqf : in some English dialects, torch = flashlight

Comment: Saying that water is the "key fuel component" in this is a bit like claiming that water is the "key component" of nuclear fusion because it's where we get the Deuterium. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar *enriched* water.

Comment: @Mindwin: Think about that composite noun for a moment. "Enriched water". How do you *get* "enriched water" (a.k.a. "heavy water")? You can't magick another neutron into a hydrogen core. But you can have lots of hydrogen cores undergo a process that *existing* deuterium cores have a higher chance of getting through, giving you a water that is "richer" in deuterium. You still *start* with *normal* water. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar same way as enriched uranium starts with normal uranium. =) My previous comment should be read more like something that came out of the marketing dept.

Comment: @Mindwin: Well, that's rich. ;-)

Comment: Unless they have a mining source of CaC2

Comment: Better analogy: Saying that this car runs on water is like saying that cars with gasoline engines run on oxygen.

Comment: I think the most important claim made in the source is that the fuel costs 10..20 Rs/liter (compared to 70 for gasoline) - per liter of what (just the CaC2? Combined with water? The acetylene gas itself?), and whether a liter of whatever is being measured has comparable energy to a liter of gasoline (or comparable fuel per distance to a car with a gasoline engine)

Comment: @Mindwin "enriched water" - you don't mean "dehydrated water"? See http://www.bernardfoods.com/foodservice/beverages/dehydatedwater.htm

Comment: @Random832: That's why I always prefer $/km over $/liter. $/km always measures the cost of using a vehicle regardless of the details of efficiency or energy density

Comment: There may be a bit of a [safety issue](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DN-Qp2Lvrliw&h=wAQFqCrKr).

Comment: @hdhondt <pokerface> no. See above comment. </pokerface>

Comment: @slebetman that doesn't help anyone figure out if something is technically feasible, only if it's economically feasible. Economic feasibility changes for each new circumstance/economy/consumer. Add to it practices like [loss-leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_leader), and I would prefer knowing the factors that actually matter (energy density), than a highly imperfect proxy. This is similar to saying "place A is a 3 hour drive, I don't know or care about kilometres". Or for that matter, "my elbow is the meter".

Comment: @MilindR: Energy density is a very imperfect proxy for measuring cost (see Random832's comment on the primary claim). I'd rather measure cost directly with $/km

Comment: @slebetman It's an imperfect proxy both ways. Unless you're limited in capacity to understand, or you _really_ don't care, why would you prefer $/km rather than $/L and km/L ? the latter enables you to calculate feasibility in many more circumstances. it's like having 3 data points instead of the function generating it.

Comment: @MilindR: The claim specifically discusses fuel costs and that it's cheaper in terms of $/L which is misleading (especially since he's measuring litres of water, not acetylene gas generated, besides, 1L acetylene gas is less dense than 1L liquid petrol). $/km would directly compare costs and expose that the carbide+water thing as more expensive than petrol. Why I didn't mention $/L - because that's already in the claim, I don't need to repeat it. Why not km/L - because if you have $/km you can directly compare costs..

Comment: .. It's not that I don't see the use of other metrics. It's that people rarely compare $/km - which is a more useful metric for the layman

Comment: I... think that Calcium Carbide has nothing to do with methane. Partial combustion of methane is used to prepare acetylene directly, without using Calcium Carbide. They are two completely separate ways of getting the same compound.

Answer (score 3):

Not much to add to the chemical/technical background already mentioned by [hdhondt](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/32440/32151).

A carbide (or better an acetylene) motor for the use in vehicles was invented much earlier. The earliest [reference (german)](http://dingler.culture.hu-berlin.de/article/pj334/ar334015) I've found is an article in „Mitteilungen des schweizerischen Azetylen-Vereins“, Heft 10 vom Oktober 1918 (Bulletin of the Suisse Acetylene-Company - Issue 10 October, 1918) which mentions experiments with a "light motor vehicle" (mileage ~35 pounds of calcium carbide/100 miles), a 6 hp motor cargoship and a motorcycle with a range of ~75 miles.

The linked article also mentions similar tests in Germany (pre-WW1) which weren't very "satisfactory".